# Using Excel VBA to Open a workbook, copy values from certian cells, save the new form, then close the opened workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Workbook that is being used to track project information.  I have been updating the workbook functionality and macros, but currently do not have means of transferring all of the user entered information to the updated workbook.  I am creating an "IMPORT" button that will allow the user to select an older version of the workbook, open that workbook (wbout), copy over the values into the new workbook (wbin), save the new workbook, and close the old one without saving it.

At this point I am having troubles with the Workbooks.Open command.  The line that has the command opens the workbook, then I get a

> Run Time Error '91': Object Variable or With Block variable not set.

Can someone please advise as to what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

```
Private Sub ImportPrj1_Click()
Dim rngin As Range
Dim rngout As Range
Dim wsin As Worksheet
Dim wsout As Worksheet
Dim wbin As Workbook
Dim wbout As Workbook
Dim namein As String
Dim folderin As Variant
Dim msg As String

Set wbin = ActiveWorkbook

folderin = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsm", 1, "Select Older Version to transfer information from.", , False)
If folderin = False Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wbout = Workbooks.Open(folderin)  ' <--- Line executes but returns error
Set wsin = wbin.Worksheet("P3 PayOuts")
Set wsout = wbout.Worksheets("P3 PayOuts")
wsin.Range("H4").Value = wsout.Range("H4").Value
wsin.Range("C9:V10").Value = wsout.Range("C9:V10").Value
wsin.Range("K3:K5").Value = wsout.Range("K3:K5").Value
wsin.Range("L3:L5").Value = wsout.Range("L3:L5").Value

' Create File name, save new tracker, close old tracker, make summary active,screen updates = true
namein = InputBox("Enter 1-2 word project identifier to be used in the File Name", "File Name")
namein = "Project Tracker V1.2" & namein
msg = "Project Tracker with imported data will be saved in the same folder as the old version"
msg = msg & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "File Name: " & namein & ".xlsm"
MsgBox (msg)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

folderin = Application.wbout.Path
namein = folderin & "\" & namein
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=namein, FileFormat:=52 ' xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

Workbooks(wbout).Close (False)

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

wbin.Worksheets("Summary").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wbout = Workbooks.Open(folderin)`

Comment: With that change now I get the "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: I believe `Set wsout = wbout.Worksheets("P3 PayOuts")` should be `Set wsout = wbout.Worksheet("P3 PayOuts")`

Comment: Maldred - Went through and made that revision.  Still doesn't fix initial issue of opening the WBOUT file.

Comment: @Maldred no. The collection is `Worksheets`, with the "s". If `wbout` is declared `As Workbook` you even get IntelliSense for it - pretty hard to mess *that* up.

Comment: @Mat's Mug,  The 438 error is occurring at the same spot as the 91 error, at the   ` Set wbout = Workbooks.Open(folderin)`    command.  The new workbook opens, but then the error pops up.

Comment: No. The error 438 is occurring at the next statement, where you're invoking some non-existing `Workbook.Worksheet` member. Put a breakpoint on the statement immediately after the `Workbooks.Open` instruction, you'll see it's getting hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting error 91 because you're assigning an object reference without the `Set` keyword, here:

```
wbout = Workbooks.Open(folderin)
```

But once *that* is fixed, you're getting error 438 because you're referring to a member that isn't defined on the `Excel.Workbook` interface:

```
Set wsin = wbin.Worksheet("P3 PayOuts")
```

That's `Worksheets`, not `Worksheet`.

Both of these bugs (and possibly many more - you have unused variables in there, and then I expect `NewBook` to blow up as well) could have been avoided by inspecting with [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com), an open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage.

Comment: Thanks @Mat'sMug.  That worked up to the NewBook, which I will work on rectifying.  I would condsider your Rubberduck (despite the relentless plugging for it) but as I am not an admin on my system, I cannot utilize it.

Comment: Feel a little goofy that it was just the difference between worksheet and worksheets as I have used worksheets everywhere else in the darned thing.

Comment: I try (harder than it seems!) to avoid being *relentless* about *plugging* it, but given it's open-source and free (I'm not getting a single penny out of it, the related blog, or anything closely or remotely related to it), and that 90% of the inspections that were implemented originate with SO questions and "how could we help people avoid posting an embarrassing question with that issue", I can assure you that my only goal is to make the VBIDE a better IDE, and help the world write better VBA code.

Comment: Thanks again Mat's Mug for the help.  I will look into adding it at home to try and help.  Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0):

Try entering this line into the code above "Wbout = Workbooks.Open(folderin)" line:

```
Tmp = MsgBox(folderin,vbokonly,"folderin:")
```

If the result is just a filename (E.g. not a full path), try the following amendment (you can then delete the above):

```
Set WBout = Workbooks.Open(WBin.Path & "\" & folderin)
```

I also typically use the Sheets collection instead of the Worksheets...not sure if that will change anything, but I have had issues with Worksheets in the past.

Comment: The `Sheets` collection can contain `Chart` objects, not just `Worksheets`. It's a much better idea to use the `Worksheets` collection if you expect to get a `Worksheet` object.

Comment: Well pointed out. I’ve just had issues working with the Worksheets method, but then again I tend to control what goes into the workbook.